# JSch session.connect() hungs with CoreFTP

Tags: sftp, jsch, hung

I have CoreFTP configured for localhost and the next code:

```
JSch.setLogger(new MyJschLogger()); //class for console output

Session session = jsch.getSession("user", "localhost", 21);

Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);

session.setPassword("password");
session.connect();
```

when program achieves `connect()`, two messages appear at console output:

```
INFO: Connecting to localhost port 21
INFO: Connection established
```

...and nothing more happens. After some minutes, `connection is closed by foreign host` exception appears.

Why?

Thanks for all!

Comment: What is the relation between CoreFTP and JSch here?

Comment: Ah, are you using [coreFTP server](http://www.coreftp.com/server/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port 21 is the normal port for [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP). JSch is only an [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) client, with support for [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol) in the [ChannelSFTP](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html) class. JSch knows nothing about FTP (and SFTP is unrelated to FTP, other than by name and that it allows similar things).

You need to setup your server to use the SSH protocol (usually on port 22, but you can use any port, as long as you use the same port on the client). See [the documentation](http://www.coreftp.com/server/help/Secure_Access.htm) - I think you have to check the SSH check box.

Also, if your code is nothing more than what you posted, then nothing more than connecting will happen. To transfer files, you will need to open a [ChannelSFTP](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html), and issue the right commands (e.g. call one or more of the put/get methods).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar issue:

```
"ERROR 2016-04-27 15:05:16,489 [CollectionThreadPool-0] com.dell.supportassist.collector.cli.executor.SSHExecutor: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: connection is closed by foreign host"
```

In my case, channel was getting closed randomly. And when we are trying to re-connect the channel then it was not re-connecting and failing.

This was happening due to looping logic while connecting, so I tried to connect the session without channel by calling method `connectWithoutOpenChannel` instead of `connectinternal()`. This resolved my issue.